# How to pass on an Array of objects to perform CoreData updates in background

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to save an entity in CoreData using performBackgroundTask. Facing issues while passing the array of objects. Below is the code.

Goal is to save core data entity in the background without freezing the NStableView or any other control/

```
public class Transaction: NSManagedObject {
    
    @NSManaged public var transDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var account: [Account]?
    
    
    class func addTransaction(transDate : Date, transAccount : [Account]){
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (context) in
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Transaction", in: context)
            let CD = Transaction(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
            CD.transDate = transDate //updated successfully
            do {
                let account = try context.existingObject(with: transAccount.objectID) as? Account // "This property (ObjectID) is defined on NSAtomicStoreCacheNode and may not be available in this context. Please guide what change is required in case we are passing the array of the objects
            } catch {
                print("something went wrong")
            }
            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("error in saving Transaction data")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply loop over the array `transAccount` and call context.existingObject for each object and add the result to another array that you then assign or append to Transaction.account

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, it helped! I am able to move forward. It answered my question. I am hit with an error while assigning to the CD.account that is a NSset, used NSset(Array: person), will troubleshoot more. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When you post answers in comments, the question remains marked as unanswered even though an answer exists. That makes this site harder for everyone to use. Would you consider writing your answers as answers more often instead of comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Joakim Danielson. Below is the response.

Simply loop over the array transAccount and call context.existingObject for each object and add the result to another array that you then assign or append to Transaction.account

Comment: Glad you got it solved, perhaps you could also add the code to your answer so others can see what helped you solve the problem.